# Video player for OS X (QTKit, ffmpeg)

Tags: macos, video, ffmpeg

What is the best approach to create video player for Mac with maximum video formats support?

It is posible to add external codecs to QTKit?
If not anybody may give step step tutorial how to compiler ffmpeg for mac (right way, google give me a lot of ways...), how to add ffmpeg libraries to Xcode project.

Big Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can easily compile ffmpeg by regular "./configure && make" and add built static libraries into your xcode project. More sophisticated approach is to create xcode projects for each ffmpeg library (libavcodec/format/util/etc) and add them as nested projects.

> It is posible to add external codecs to QTKit?

Check Perian project:

- http://trac.cod3r.com/perian/browser
- http://perian.org/

Comment: Thanks for reply, Vadim! Which ffmpeg static libraries i must add into Xcode project? When i add libavcodec.a & libavformat.a from /usr/local/lib Xcode give me error. Maybe I'm not correctly add the library. I copy these libraries into a separate folder, and add to the project. How to add ffmpeg library from hidden folder /usr to project?

Comment: I use pretty old ffmpeg version in my projects, so in my case the libraries are:

Comment: (accidentaly pressed Enter :/ )

I use pretty old ffmpeg version, so it has following libraries

libavcodec/libavcodec.a
libavdevice/libavdevice.a
libavformat/libavformat.a
libavutil/libavutil.a
libswscale/libswscale.a (note that libswscale is under GPL license)

Just execute this command `find . -name '*.a'` after `make`.

> How to add ffmpeg library from hidden folder /usr?

I wouldn't add libraries from /usr/lib - just find them in ffmpeg directory (using Finder) and drag-drop them into your xcode project. Or put "-L <ffmpeg dir> -lavcodec -lavformat -lavutil -lswscale" in linker options